# Efficiently replacing compound words in a tokenized array of strings. Python

Tags: python, arrays, nlp

What is the most efficient way to replace compound words inside an array of strings.

```
text = ['San', 'Francisco', 'is', 'foggy', '.','Viva', 'Las', 'Vegas','.']


replacements = {'san_francisco':['San Francisco'],
                'las_vegas': ['Las Vegas'],
                }

text2= ' '.join(text)

for key, value in replacements.items():
    text2=text2.replace(value[0],key)

final=text2.split(' ')

print(final)
```

So this method reconstructs the whole string, loops through the dictionary and replaces the text. Sublime text indicates that this takes 0.2s. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: for me it shows 0.0 s

Comment: @AvinashRaj it differs from computer. Are there ways to avoid the loops before going to `Cython`?

Comment: Are the "compound words" always two words in length total or can they be longer?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry I did not see it I was rewriting the question because it was not as clear. I did not mean to delete :(

Comment: @ben_frankly any length and the values of the dict is in an array in cases where there are two forms, but I forgot to add the additional for loop to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't yet profiled this on a larger dataset but this may be more efficient. A lot of the "heavy-lifting" in your solution is done via the `replace` method so whatever way is more efficient will depend heavily on how optimized the cPython `replace` method is (i.e. they may use some clever tricks to make it run very fast).

```
text = ['San', 'Francisco', 'is', 'foggy', '.','Viva', 'Las', 'Vegas','.', "wild", "wild", "west"]

replacements = {
'San':  {'Francisco': 'san_francisco'},
'Las': {'Vegas': 'las_vegas'},
'wild': {'wild': {'west': 'wild_wild_west'}}
}

for i in range(0, len(text)-1):

    if text[i] is None:
        continue

    replacement_value = replacements.get(text[i])
    if replacement_value is None:.
        continue

    number_of_items_to_delete = 0
    while isinstance(replacement_value, dict):
        number_of_items_to_delete += 1
        replacement_value = replacement_value.get(text[i + number_of_items_to_delete])

    text[i] = replacement_value

    for j in range(i+1, i+1 + number_of_items_to_delete):
        text[j] = None

text = [n for n in text if n is not None]
print (text)
```

We use a nested dictionary for our lookup table now. Note I have "flipped" the lookup table so that the key comes from the values in the word list whose replacement we want to lookup in the table.

The algorithm can be described as follows:

- Iterate over the word list.
- If a given word is found in the lookup table, lookup its value in the lookup table. If the value is another dictionary, check if the next word in the word list is in that nested dictionary we just retrieved. Keep track of how many words forward in the list we are looking at.
- When the item retrieved in the lookup table is no longer a dictionary (when we find the actual replacement string) we replace the current word with the replacement string. Then, however many words forward we looked to get to end of our lookup table, we replace those indices with `None`
- Once we are doing iterating, we then remove all the instances of "None" from the word list.